# Documentation timing out - logged in viewing C# Features Topic

Tags: bug, documentation, google-chrome, performance

Several times now the following page loads partially but then hangs in Chrome

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/24/c-sharp-6-0-features

It works fine while logged out in cognito.

I've restarted and upgraded from Chrome 51 to 52 to no avail.

In developer tools I see that the following resource failed to load
https://engine.adzerk.net/ados.js (but loads in a separate tab)

A call to google-analytics and scorecardreearch appear to be pending.

Comment: I'm sure this is a dupe. Your not the first to say this. I just can't find it in the barage of documentation issues

Comment: I had a good look but can't see one. Will reference if I come across it.

Comment: @Liam though I'm not even editing, just trying to load.

Comment: @Liam marked this as dupe, will just comment on original question